# SwiftUI: how to have image in list view not have same action as list item?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I have a list inside a view. Inside the list, `items` are iterated through to populate the list.  When you click on each list item, I want to navigate to another view.
This is working as expected but I want to have a `Button` represented by a circle in each list item that can be clicked independently without navigating to the second view.  Right now, clicking the circle just takes me to 2nd view.  How can I accomplish this?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: OtherView(name: "test"),
                    label: {
                       Text("Navigate")
                    })
                HStack {
                    Image("1")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 32.0, height: 32.0)
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "circle")
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but I think you should put the text, image, and button all into the navigation link with a HStack.   and one thing that helped me in a similar problem is `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())`

Comment: Make a `RowView(item:item)` and but what you have inside your `ForEach` in there.   Each `Item` will have a `RowView` and you can manipulate individually in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this with `List`. You can use `VStack` or `LazyVStack` inside a `ScrollView` as an alternative solution